# Location of jfxrt.jar on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, javafx-2

I'm trying to compile/run some JavaFX code.
On my PC I reference: C:/Program Files/Oracle/JavaFX 2.1 SDK/rt/lib/jfxrt.jar

My understanding is that JavaFX is included in JDK 7 on Mac OS x but I cannot find jfxrt.jar in:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit (Nov 2019)**: Currently OpenJDK doesn't include OpenJFX. Some OpenJDK providers include OpenJFX into their installation. For the rest, you can use maven or gradle to include it into your projects.

---

Java7: `jre/lib/jfxrt.jar`

Java8: `jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar`

you can find it using `find $JAVA_HOME -name jfxrt.jar`

---

Since Java9 there is no `jfxrt.jar`, it's now a set of modules:

```
./jmods/javafx.base.jmod
./jmods/javafx.media.jmod
./jmods/javafx.swing.jmod
./jmods/javafx.controls.jmod
./jmods/javafx.web.jmod
./jmods/javafx.fxml.jmod
./jmods/javafx.graphics.jmod
```

Comment: im getting `-bash: cd: Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/jre: No such file or directory`

Comment: It is not located anymore in that folder, nor in jdk8, jdk12 and jdk13. https://pastebin.com/umtwAWjp

Comment: @aironman, OpenJFX is not a part of OpenJDK, so not all installations have it. adoptopenjdk-8 doesn't include OpenJFX. You need either install it separately or use cobundled image like ZuluFX: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?&version=java-11-lts&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk-fx

Comment: Also, OpenJFX is not a part of OpenJDK so you don't find it in the files you've mentioned. But you can find it in a specially cobundled binaries: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk-fx You can read why OpenJFX is not a part of OpenJDK here: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/the-future-of-javafx-and-other-java-client-roadmap-updates